# how to create index on joining tables in sql

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle11g

I am tuning an SQL query. When I checked the explanation plan, tables INTERFACE_ADT_AOE_MASTER and TEST_REQUIRED are going for full table scan. I want to create an index

**Table structure**

```
Table ***INTERFACE_ADT_AOE_MASTER

Columns***
TESTCODE_MASTER_ID,
SOURCE_SYSTEM,
TEST_CODE,
QUESTION_CODE,
EAST_WEST_FLAG,
UOM,
STATUS,
MATCH_TYPE,
CREATED_DT,
STATUS_UPDATED_DTM,
QUESTION_CAPTION


Table ***TEST_REQUIRED***
Columns
TEST_REQUIRED_ID  Primary Key, 
TEST_ID,
REQUIRED_TEST_CODE,
CREATED_DATE,
MODIFIED_DATE
```

This is the sub query where these tables are going for full table scan.

```
(SELECT TEST_ID
      FROM TEST_REQUIRED
      WHERE REQUIRED_TEST_CODE IN
        (SELECT TEST_CODE FROM INTERFACE_ADT_AOE_MASTER
        )
      )
```

`REQUIRED_TEST_CODE` and `TEST_CODE`  are same.

Can anyone suggest me how to create an index for it? Thanks in advance

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu   Oracle 11 g

Comment: sorry never used oracle but in sql-server through SSMS we can use the query execution plan to get suggested index to create

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index on INTERFACE_ADT_AOE_MASTER.TEST_CODE and changing your subquery to:

```
(SELECT TEST_ID
      FROM TEST_REQUIRED
      WHERE EXISTS 
         ( SELECT 1 FROM INTERFACE_ADT_AOE_MASTER WHERE TEST_CODE = REQUIRED_TEST_CODE )
)
```

Note that there can be different reasons for the full table scan: without seeing the full query and the EXPLAIN PLAN it's difficult to know if this will help.